# 'The picture hung crooked on the wall'

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

Is it more correct to say 'The picture hung crooked on the wall' or 'The picture hung crookedly on the wall'? My instinct is that the first one sounds better to me as a native speaker, but someone else I was talking to was convinced that only the second is correct. What's better here?

Comment: The problem is "crooked" isn't an adverb, it's an adjective. "Crookedly" _is_ and adverb and is therefore correct. Some verb → adverb forms don't take the -ly, but in this case, it does. That being said, in this case saying crooked for crookedly doesn't change the meaning of what you said.

Comment: It's one of those ugly cases where it's easier to just straighten the picture than work out which word for "askew" applies.

Comment: @VampDuc In _The rose blushed pink_, pink isn't an adverb either. Some verbs 'take' adjectives, in depictive or resultative constructions. Collins Cobuild includes  _stand_ (she stood totally still) and _hang_ (the clouds of smoke hung motionless over the valley).

Comment: @Edwin: I don't know what the "adverbial" form of ***still*** might be (perhaps I should say *I **still** don't know!* :) but a more clear-cut illustration might be to contrast *She stood naked* with *?She stood **nakedly***.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I meant that that was what his friend's problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you imagine a pair of commas added:

> The picture hung, crooked, on the wall"

you can see that *crooked* is an adjective.

It's not too harmful perhaps to then take the commas away.

*Crooked* describes the picture; *crookedly*, how it hangs.

Comment: Not quite. Both _crooked_ and _crookedly_ describe how the picture is hanging (a crooked picture needs to be reframed, repainted or exhibited as a Picasso and sold for millions). But the adverb _does_ emphasise 'the way it is _hanging_', the adjective 'the _way_ it is hanging'. In some cases, the difference in emphasis might be more useful, but here there's little to choose between.